# Как называется этот виджет в Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, combobox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужен такой виджет в Qt, но чтоб он был не просто списком, а можно было вписывать свое значение.

Спасибо.

Comment: комбобокс. И что вы имеете ввиду под "вписывать свое значение"? Добавить новые строки в список, или просо использовать его как поле ввода? Если второе, то ищите свойство `setEditable` или типа того.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виджет называется `QComboBox`, а чтобы была возможность редактировать значение нужно установить значение `Editable` в `True`:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


app = Qt.QApplication([])

w = Qt.QComboBox()
w.setEditable(True)
w.addItems(['abc', '123', '!@#'])
w.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]